# Advance installer how to check install dir is empty

Tags: installation, conditional-statements, advanced-installer

I have created an installer.
I need to insert a condition:
If installation dir isn't empty the installer must show a pop-up message.
I don't find the right conditions

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thread from the Advanced Installer forums covering exactly this scenario:

- https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=30532